# Nestjs: the methode of JwtStrategy doesn't work

Tags: nestjs-jwt

I'm trying to use jwt in nest
Everything is ok, but validate function is not working in jwt.strategy.ts

this is my jwt.strategy.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
     private userService:UserService
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey:"mysecretkey",
    });
  }

  async validate(payload:any) {
      console.log('this is payload'+payload)
```

it prints: this is payload undefine

user.modul

```
@Module({
  exports:[UserService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService,JwtStrategy],
  imports : [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),PassportModule.register(
    {defaultStrategy:'jwt'}),
  JwtModule.register({secret:'mysecretkey',signOptions:{expiresIn:3600000}})]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

When i request in postman, i get satus:401 Unauthorized and in termenal show : payload undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, then you have to define the JwtAuthGuard class which extends the built-in AuthGuard.

```
//jwt-auth.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

Then, you can implement protected route and its associated Guard.
Like,

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get('profile')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
```

Refer [Nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)

---

**EDIT:**

You need to generate userToken everytime you create a new user. Return this userToken in response of CreateUser API which can be used by the frontend. Also, the userToken generated should be used in API requests wherever needed.

Inject this AuthService in your UserService class and call this method to generate jwt token.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService) {}

  getJwtToken(userId: number, phone: string) {
    const payload = { userId: userId, userPhone: phone }; //Set whatever data you need to keep in your jwt
    return this.jwtService.sign(payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: i do that but it still not working and the payload is undifened

Comment: ok. I have a question, why are you injecting UserService in jwt.strategy.ts file?

Comment: in userService i implement methede findUserByEmail in validate i need to use this method for get informations about user from database

Comment: oh okay got it.

Comment: Please check the edit in the answer and let me know if you have implemented that already or not.

Comment: If not, then can you tell me how are you generating jwt and sending it while requesting from postman?

Comment: now it work  thank you brother for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too.
In my case I use such secretOrKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || 'SECRET'

And I found that in JwtStrategy (that extends PassportStrategy(Strategy)) was used process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, but on auth module in JwtModule.register({secret: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || 'SECRET', ...}) was used 'SECRET'!

Check you secret key.